Is External Direct product equal to Internal Direct product in case of finite abelian groups?
Let $G$ be a finite Abelian group and let $H_1, H_2, \ldots, H_r$ be normal proper subgroups of it.
If $G$ is the internal direct product of $H_1, H_2, \ldots, H_r$ i.e. if $G=H_1\times H_2\times \ldots \times H_r$ then $G$ is isomorphic to external direct product $H_1\oplus H_2\oplus \ldots \oplus H_r$. I studied this in the book "Contemporary Abstract Algebra" by Gallian.
My doubt is, can we say the converse? If $G$ is isomorphic to external direct product $H_1\oplus \ldots \oplus H_r$, can we say $G=H_1\times \ldots \times H_r$?
I tried to prove this, but confusion arises whether this is correct question or not. I also check the earlier question in here and here, however it was still not clear how shall I establish my claim, which is very special case of the above two links I think.
Any help please?

It's a duplicate and you even linked it. There the answer is given.
